# C array wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, array, wrapper, raii

As part of a larger project I wanted to write my own size once RAII C array wrapper. Now I could have just used `std::vector`, which I'm sure is the first thing almost everyone will want to point out. However, I'm doing this for learning purposes. Aside from wanting to learn more, `Simple_Array` is not exactly designed to replicate what vector does: it should not resize <sup>1</sup>, it should be safe to inherit from.

I'm concerned with both style and efficacy so aside from any and all criticism, I'd love to know if I'm using `std::move` appropriately. Since it is just being used on `_size` and `_data` presumably this changes nothing as they are built in types, is it good etiquette to use `std::move` anyway?

```
template <typename Ty>
class Simple_Array
{
    size_t _size;
    Ty* _data;

public:
    Simple_Array(size_t size) : _size(size), _data(new Ty[size]) {}

    template <class It>
    Simple_Array(It first, It last) :
        Simple_Array(std::distance(first, last))
    {
        unchecked_copy(first, last);
    }

    Simple_Array(const Simple_Array& other) :
        Simple_Array(other.begin(), other.end()) {}

    Simple_Array(Simple_Array&& other) :
        _size(std::move(other._size)), _data(std::move(other._data))
    {
        other._size = 0;
        other._data = nullptr;
    }

    Simple_Array& operator=(const Simple_Array& other) {
        if (this == &other)
            return *this;

        if (_size != other._size) {
            if (_data != nullptr)
                delete[] _data;

            _size = other._size;
            _data = new Ty[_size];
        }

        unchecked_copy(other.begin(), other.end());

        return *this;
    }

    Simple_Array& operator=(Simple_Array&& other) {
        if (this == &other)
            return *this;

        if (_data != nullptr)
            delete[] _data;

        _size = std::move(other._size);
        _data = std::move(other._data);

        other._size = 0;
        other._data = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~Simple_Array() {
        if (_data != nullptr)
            delete[] _data;
    }

    const size_t size() const { return _size; }

    Ty* begin() const { return _data; }
    Ty* end() const { return _data + _size; }
    const Ty* cbegin() const { return _data; }
    const Ty* cend() const { return _data + _size; }
    const Ty* at(size_t index) const { return _data + index; }

    Ty& get(size_t index) { return _data[index]; }
    const Ty get(size_t index) const { return _data[index]; }
    Ty& operator[](size_t index) { return _data[index]; }
    const Ty operator[](size_t index) const { return _data[index]; }

private:
    template <class It>
    unchecked_copy(It first, It last) {
#ifdef _SECURE_SCL // MSVC requires checked iterators or disabled warnings.
        std::copy(first, last, stdext::make_unchecked_array_iterator(_data));
#else
        std::copy(first, last, _data);
#endif
    }
};
```

I haven't tested this on anything other than MSVC, and I'd appreciate any criticism on portability.

<sup>1</sup> Resizing can occur during copy / move assignment, but I'm ok with that.

Comment: leak in move assign, `this->_data` doesn't get freed

Comment: @ratchetfreak Woops, that should have been obvious! Oh well, I updated it with the fix, thanks!

Comment: Please see: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c

Comment: @Deduplicator Ahh, makes sense, thanks for the pointer, I'll post an answer to my own question with the new code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Construction**

In your constructor from iterators:

```
template <class It>
Simple_Array(It first, It last) :
    Simple_Array(std::distance(first, last))
{
    unchecked_copy(first, last);
}
```

You do two things: first you *default-construct* a `n` objects, and then you *copy-assign* them. This is both inefficient and reduces the usability of your class. What if `Ty` is not default constructible? Now I can't have a `Simple_Array` of it!

Prefer to use the global operator new to just give you uninitialized data, and then placement new into each slot:

```
template <class It>
Simple_Array(It first, It last)
: _size(std::distance(first, last))
{
    _data = static_cast<Ty*>(::operator new(_size * sizeof(Ty)));

    Ty* cur = _data;
    for (; first != last; ++first, ++cur) {
        new (cur) T{*first};
    }
}
```

You may also want to add SFINAE to make sure that this constructor is only viable if `Ty` is constructible from `*It`.

Note that we have to initialize `_data` the same way everywhere, so we'll need to change the other constructor too:

```
SimpleArray(size_t size) : _size(size)
{   
    _data = static_cast<T*>(::operator new(_size * sizeof(T)));
    for (Ty* cur = _data; cur != _data + _size; ++cur) {
        new (cur) Ty();
    }
}
```

**Initializer List constructor**

Would be helpful to add an `initializer_list` constructor. Especially since you already have a two-iterator one:

```
Simple_Array(std::initializer_list<Ty> elems)
: Simple_Array(elems.begin(), elems.end())
{ }
```

**Copy/Move Assignment**

The best way to write copy assignment is copy-and-swap, and the best way to write move assignment is swap. Self-assignment is a pessimization, since that's going to be a rare occurrence anyway. Plus, with swap, we can make everything `noexcept`:

```
Simple_Array& operator=(Simple_Array rhs) noexcept {  // copy/move
    swap(rhs);                                        // and swap
    return *this;
}

void swap(Simple_Array& rhs) noexcept {
    std::swap(_size, rhs._size);
    std::swap(_data, rhs._data);
}
```

As a possible optimization, the copy assignment can reuse the same buffer if it's already large enough and copy assignment for `Ty` cannot throw (simply then manually destroy all the leftover elements).

**Virtual destructor??**

There is no reason for the destructor to be virtual. You're adding a vtable to your class for no reason. With the new change to using `operator new` to allocate the array, we now need to use `operator delete` to delete it (along with manually destroying every element):

```
~Simple_Array() {
    for (T* cur = begin(); cur != end(); ++cur) {
        cur->~Ty();
    }

    ::operator delete(_data);
}
```

**const methods should still return references**

Your `operator[]` and `get()` for non-const return `Ty&` but for const return `const Ty`. Why make the extra copy? You should give back a `const Ty&`.

**`at()` should bounds check**

By convention, `at()` should (a) check that the index is within bounds and throw `std::out_of_range()` if it's not and (b) return a reference. That's what [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at), [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/at), [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at), [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at), etc. all do.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32834/discussion-on-answer-by-barry-c-array-wrapper).

Answer (score 3):

Everything Barry said.

In addition there are a couple of types I would add.

```
template <typename Ty>
class Simple_Array
{
    public:
        typedef   Ty           value_type;
        typedef   Ty&          reference;
        typedef   Ty*          pointer;
        typedef   Ty const&    const_reference;
        typedef   Ty const*    const_pointer;

        typedef   std::size_t        size_type;
        typedef   std::ptrdiff_t     difference_type;

        typedef   Ty*          iterator;
        typedef   Ty const*    const_iterator;
```

Modify your standard methods to use these types. This allows the standard library to produce optimal code when using algorithms.

Comment: OK, didn't know stl algorithms would take advantage of that but it makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Presumably by `T* iterator` and `T const* const_iterator` you mean `Ty...`. Also By `std::difference_t` do you mean `std::ptrdiff_t`? Can't find anything about `difference_t`.

Comment: @AlexeiBarnes: Yes on all counts.

Comment: Awesome, once I have figured out some things about the copy swap idiom and SFINAE I'll post the revised code including this.

Comment: @AlexeiBarnes: Just do it in a new question.